Mail.app keeps quitting on its own with no crash report. How do I figure out why?
I'm running macOS 13.6.5 and for some reason starting in the last week, Mail.app keeps crashing. Except it's not 'crashing' strictly, because there's no crash log in ~/Library/Logs/DiagonsticReports, nor any indication from the system that it was anything other than a normal termination. I haven't changed its settings, updated the system, or done anything I can think of that could explain this sudden change in behavior. So far the "crash" has only happened when it's in the background, so I haven't found a way consistently trigger it, other than leaving Mail running and waiting long enough.
I tried running Mail from a terminal window, i.e. executing /System/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail, but for some reason that actually works around the issue and it stops quitting. So I can't get any useful information from its console output.
Is there anything else I can do to figure out why this is happening and fix it?
Edit 1:
I took Linc D's excellent suggestion and found some logging that occurs immediately prior to Mail terminating. There was a lot of output, and the only line of type error was:
runningboardd: (RunningBoard) [com.apple.runningboard:process] [app<application.com.apple.mail.1152921500311886404.1152921500311886479(501)>:81815] terminate_with_reason() failed with error: -1

However, if I look at the proceeding second before Mail terminates and check default-level log entries too, I find:
runningboardd: (RunningBoard) [com.apple.runningboard:connection] Received termination request from [osservice<com.apple.cache_delete(501)>:675] on <RBSProcessPredicate <RBSProcessBundleIdentifierPredicate "com.apple.mail">> with context <RBSTerminateContext| code:0xBADDD15C explanation:CacheDeleteAppContainerCaches requesting termination assertion for com.apple.mail reportType:None maxTerminationResistance:NonInteractive attrs:[
<RBSPreventLaunchLimitation| <RBSProcessPredicate <RBSProcessBundleIdentifierPredicate "com.apple.mail">> allow:(null)>
]>

That on its own isn't too revealing to me, but maybe someone can decipher it? Does this have something to do with deleting a cache?
In case it helps, here's the 50 lines proceeding that termination entry that have something to do with Mail.app, either coming from Mail or having the word "mail" in the message:
2024-10-03 11:38:16.108443-0400 0x14ba651  Default     0x0                  81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] Annotations changed, re-performing query for continuous discovery, report block = <0x600003dbfb40>.
2024-10-03 11:38:16.108455-0400 0x14ba370  Default     0x0                  81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] Annotations changed, re-performing query for continuous discovery, report block = <0x600003ec1770>.
2024-10-03 11:38:16.108459-0400 0x14ba819  Default     0x0                  81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] Annotations changed, re-performing query for continuous discovery, report block = <0x600003ec1bf0>.
2024-10-03 11:38:16.108506-0400 0x14ba819  Default     0x1608a9d            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Beginning discovery for flags: 0, point: com.apple.ui-services
2024-10-03 11:38:16.108506-0400 0x14ba651  Default     0x1608972            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Beginning discovery for flags: 0, point: com.apple.email.extension
2024-10-03 11:38:16.108510-0400 0x14ba370  Default     0x1608a9d            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Beginning discovery for flags: 0, point: com.apple.services
2024-10-03 11:38:16.119210-0400 0x14ba370  Default     0x1608972            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Completed discovery. Final # of matches: 0
2024-10-03 11:38:16.119266-0400 0x14ba819  Default     0x1608972            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] <PKDiscoveryDriver:0x6000017a0f00> delivering update to host (0 plugins)
2024-10-03 11:38:16.119298-0400 0x14ba819  Activity    0x1641b0b            81815  0    Mail: (ExtensionFoundation) discovering extensions
2024-10-03 11:38:16.119381-0400 0x14ba370  Default     0x1641b0b            81815  0    Mail: (MailKit) [com.apple.email:MEAppExtensionsController] Found 0 email extensions
2024-10-03 11:38:16.119449-0400 0x14ba370  Default     0x1641b0b            81815  0    Mail: (MailKit) [com.apple.email:MailExtensions] Current Mail Extensions for processing updates -
Enabled Extensions - (
)
All Extensions (
)
2024-10-03 11:38:16.182568-0400 0x14ba370  Default     0x1608a9d            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Completed discovery. Final # of matches: 4
2024-10-03 11:38:16.182646-0400 0x14ba819  Default     0x1608a9d            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] <PKDiscoveryDriver:0x6000017304e0> delivering update to host (4 plugins)
2024-10-03 11:38:16.182674-0400 0x14ba819  Activity    0x1641b0c            81815  0    Mail: (ExtensionFoundation) discovering extensions
2024-10-03 11:38:16.188168-0400 0x14ba819  Default     0x1608a9d            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Completed discovery. Final # of matches: 0
2024-10-03 11:38:16.188217-0400 0x14ba370  Default     0x1608a9d            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] <PKDiscoveryDriver:0x600001732040> delivering update to host (0 plugins)
2024-10-03 11:38:16.188248-0400 0x14ba370  Activity    0x1641b0d            81815  0    Mail: (ExtensionFoundation) discovering extensions
2024-10-03 11:38:16.509927-0400 0x14ba819  Default     0x0                  81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] Annotations changed, re-performing query for continuous discovery, report block = <0x600003dbfb40>.
2024-10-03 11:38:16.509932-0400 0x14ba370  Default     0x0                  81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] Annotations changed, re-performing query for continuous discovery, report block = <0x600003ec1770>.
2024-10-03 11:38:16.509933-0400 0x14ba651  Default     0x0                  81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] Annotations changed, re-performing query for continuous discovery, report block = <0x600003ec1bf0>.
2024-10-03 11:38:16.510036-0400 0x14ba651  Default     0x1608a9d            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Beginning discovery for flags: 0, point: com.apple.ui-services
2024-10-03 11:38:16.510039-0400 0x14ba370  Default     0x1608a9d            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Beginning discovery for flags: 0, point: com.apple.services
2024-10-03 11:38:16.510077-0400 0x14ba819  Default     0x1608972            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Beginning discovery for flags: 0, point: com.apple.email.extension
2024-10-03 11:38:16.550866-0400 0x1489069  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] filteredItemsFromItems:<private> [81815]--> <private>
2024-10-03 11:38:16.550910-0400 0x1489069  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] Requesting sharingServicesForFilteredItems:<private> mask:<private>
2024-10-03 11:38:16.550933-0400 0x1489069  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] Query extensions (async) for items: <private> onlyViewerOrEditor:1
2024-10-03 11:38:16.550980-0400 0x1489069  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] filteredItemsFromItems:<private> [81815]--> <private>
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551011-0400 0x1489069  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] Requesting sharingServicesForFilteredItems:<private> mask:<private>
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551026-0400 0x14ba819  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] Matching dictionary: <private>, attributesArray: <private>
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551045-0400 0x1489069  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] Query extensions (async) for items: <private> onlyViewerOrEditor:1
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551072-0400 0x14ba819  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] Discover extensions with attributes <private>
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551108-0400 0x1489069  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] filteredItemsFromItems:<private> [81815]--> <private>
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551116-0400 0x14ba819  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Beginning discovery for flags: 1024, point: com.apple.ui-services
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551137-0400 0x14ba651  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] Matching dictionary: <private>, attributesArray: <private>
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551142-0400 0x1489069  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] Requesting sharingServicesForFilteredItems:<private> mask:<private>
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551163-0400 0x1489069  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] Query extensions (async) for items: <private> onlyViewerOrEditor:1
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551204-0400 0x14ba651  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] Discover extensions with attributes <private>
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551237-0400 0x14ba370  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] Matching dictionary: <private>, attributesArray: <private>
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551266-0400 0x14ba370  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (ShareKit) [com.apple.sharekit:Framework] Discover extensions with attributes <private>
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551273-0400 0x14ba651  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Beginning discovery for flags: 1024, point: com.apple.ui-services
2024-10-03 11:38:16.551305-0400 0x14ba370  Default     0x1641b09            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Beginning discovery for flags: 1024, point: com.apple.ui-services
2024-10-03 11:38:16.592702-0400 0x14ba64d  Default     0x0                  81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] Annotations changed, re-performing query for continuous discovery, report block = <0x600003dbfb40>.
2024-10-03 11:38:16.592703-0400 0x14ba649  Default     0x0                  81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] Annotations changed, re-performing query for continuous discovery, report block = <0x600003ec1bf0>.
2024-10-03 11:38:16.592734-0400 0x14ba81a  Default     0x0                  81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] Annotations changed, re-performing query for continuous discovery, report block = <0x600003ec1770>.
2024-10-03 11:38:16.592785-0400 0x14ba64d  Default     0x1608972            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Beginning discovery for flags: 0, point: com.apple.email.extension
2024-10-03 11:38:16.592794-0400 0x14ba81a  Default     0x1608a9d            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Beginning discovery for flags: 0, point: com.apple.services
2024-10-03 11:38:16.592822-0400 0x14ba649  Default     0x1608a9d            81815  0    Mail: (PlugInKit) [com.apple.PlugInKit:discovery] [d <private>] <PKHost:0x6000026bebc0> Beginning discovery for flags: 0, point: com.apple.ui-services
2024-10-03 11:38:16.600462-0400 0x14ba5ac  Default     0x163a1ac            675    0    deleted: (RunningBoardServices) [com.apple.runningboard:monitor] Updating configuration of monitor <RBSProcessMonitorConfiguration| id:M675-1249 qos:17 predicates:[<RBSProcessPredicate <RBSProcessBundleIdentifierPredicate "com.apple.mail">>] descriptor:<RBSProcessStateDescriptor| values:5> events:0x0>
2024-10-03 11:38:16.608254-0400 0x14ba5cd  Default     0x16418ad            675    0    deleted: (RunningBoardServices) [com.apple.runningboard:process] Hit the server for a process handle 1d497e9500013f97 that resolved to: [app<application.com.apple.mail.1152921500311886404.1152921500311886479(501)>:81815]
2024-10-03 11:38:16.608500-0400 0x14ba6ca  Default     0x1641ee8            233    0    runningboardd: (RunningBoard) [com.apple.runningboard:connection] Received termination request from [osservice<com.apple.cache_delete(501)>:675] on <RBSProcessPredicate <RBSProcessBundleIdentifierPredicate "com.apple.mail">> with context <RBSTerminateContext| code:0xBADDD15C explanation:CacheDeleteAppContainerCaches requesting termination assertion for com.apple.mail reportType:None maxTerminationResistance:NonInteractive attrs:[
    <RBSPreventLaunchLimitation| <RBSProcessPredicate <RBSProcessBundleIdentifierPredicate "com.apple.mail">> allow:(null)>
    ]>

edit 2: I've found an explanation for what's happening at this blog post: https://bitsplitting.org/2022/06/18/purgeable-mac-apps/
Some relevant bits:

Here we have a message asserting that MarsEdit was terminated, on purpose, and better still, it includes an explanation! As far as explanations go, “CacheDeleteAppContainerCaches” is not much of one, but it did give me something to go on. Searching for the term yielded pertinent results like this post about Apple Mail and Safari “suddenly quitting.” Unfortunately, they all seem to be scratching their heads as much as I am.
...
Equipped with all this new information, what can we do about the unexpected terminations? Well, nothing. I do wish Apple’s framework would try asking nicely if the app would quit, before summarily terminating it, but I guess the thinking is that this functionality should typically only be reached in extenuating circumstances. After learning more about the issue, I confirmed with Manton that his Mac did have low disk space, so I guess it was just the system trying its best to free up space that caused the issue for him.

From Howard Oakley: https://eclecticlight.co/2019/11/07/runningboard-a-new-subsystem-in-catalina-to-detect-errors/

Catalina brings several new internal features, a few of which have been documented, but others seem to have slipped past silently. Among the latter is an active subsystem to replace an old service assertiond, which can cause apps to unexpectedly terminate – to you and me, crash – in both macOS 10.15 and iOS 13: RunningBoard.

There's another relevant thread here, referenced in that first link, which also suggests this is related to a mac subsystem that deletes caches to free up space.
The strange thing, though, is that my system drive is not low on space. It reports I have 75 GB free. So I have no idea why my macOS system has suddenly gotten aggressive about clearing Mail's cache, and forcing it to quit in order to do so. I suspect this is a bug, and not this cache clearing subsystem working as intended.
So what remains to be seen is if there's anything I can do about this! Hopefully there is a solution that can get this cache clearing system back into a properly working state.

Is the crash reproducible? Are you interacting with Mail when it crashes, or is it idle in the background? Are any plugins installed? If the answer to the last question is yes, please remove them and test.

@LincD. The crash doesn't happen when I'm interacting with Mail. So far it's only happened in the background. (I'll update my question to mention this.) As such I have no specific way to consistently trigger it immediately, though it does inevitably happen given enough time. I'm not using any plugins.

This may be a hard problem to solve. Rather than start a long conversation in the comments, I'm going to post an incomplete answer now and update it if we get somewhere.
Please launch the Console application and click Start Streaming. In the toolbar, select Errors and Faults. In the search box, enter 'com.apple.Mail' (without the quotes). From the pulldown menu next to that entry, select Subsystem.
The next time Mail crashes, note the time. Then copy the lines of output that were written to the log around that time, if any -- no more than about 50 lines. Edit your question and paste the text into a code block. If there were no log entries, just say so.
Update 1
Quit Mail if it's running. Make sure you have current backups of all data.
In the Finder, navigate to the folder Library/Containers in your home folder. This folder should have one or more subfolders, all apparently with the same name, Mail. That's not their actual name, just what the Finder displays, for reasons known only to Apple. Move all those subfolders to the Desktop. Relaunch Mail and check that your message database is intact, including attachments. The folders you moved will be recreated automatically in their original location. See whether there's an improvement in the stability of Mail. If so, and if the message database is intact, you can delete the folders you moved to the Desktop.
Update 2
While the undocumented RunningBoard framework does seem to kill processes for reasons having something to do with caching, I don't think we know that a lack of space is the reason; indeed, your example seems to show otherwise. Maybe the caches are corrupt or out of sync with the journal files.

I've done as you suggested and updated my question with more information, including log entries.

I've updated the answer with a suggested next step.

I'm giving your suggestion a try. Unfortunately I can only know if it worked if after several days Mail doesn't quit, so I'll report back later. I also did some searching with some of the log terms I found and updated my answer with more information. I know most of the explanation of the cause of the issue, but still not sure of the solution. Hopefully your suggestion will help.
